# Magento 2 : How to delete the record in custom table?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3

How to delete the record from my custom table. without using object manager?

> Example : delete from customer_comments where comments_id=124

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way just follow Magento standard. For example just check Cms magento module.

So you have a new module **app/code/MyCompany/MyModule**

**Model/Comment.php**

```
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Model;

class Comment extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_cacheTag = 'customer_comment';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'customer_comment';

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\MyCompany\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Comment::class);
    }

}
```

**Model/ResourceModel/Comment.php**

```
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel;

class Comment extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb {

    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('you_custom_table_name', 'comment_id');
    }

}
```

**Controller/Comment/Delete.php**

```
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Comment;

use MyCompany\MyModule\Model\CommentFactory;

class Delete extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**
     * @var CommentFactory
     */
    protected $_commentFactory;
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param CommentFactory $commentFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,   
        CommentFactory $commentFactory
    ) {
        $this->_commentFactory = $commentFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() 
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('comment_id');
        try {
            $model = $this->_commentFactory->create();
            $model->load($id);
            $model->delete();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `$model->load($id);` is not good way.   

load() is @deprecated because entities must not be responsible for their own loading. Service contracts should persist entities. Use resource model "load" or collections to implement service contract model loading operations.

see `\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::load()`

Answer (score 0):

[image]how to pass argument on button click to delete this id like